# Perl DBI Statement Handles and Error Handling

Tags: perl, dbi

Let's say I have a subroutine that connects to a DB. Then I want to make a query and receive the output and do something with it, of course, but what if the query is invalid?

So let's assume I have something like:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect(<db>, <user>, <pass>);
$query = 'select a, b, c from table';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
```

I realise I could also use a "do", but this will be easier for me to understand. So in a scenario where "table" doesn't have a column "c", the query would be invalid, making the handle $sth invalid and failing to execute. Right?

Now, in case of a failure as such, what happens to $sth? I can't call finish on it, because it is invalid.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. They were both very usefull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So in a scenario where "table" doesn't have a column "c", the query would be invalid, making the handle $sth invalid and failing to execute. Right?

It's not clear what you mean by "invalid".

Some drivers, like DBD::Oracle, may send the SQL statement to the server when you call `prepare`, in which case the error will be detected by the server and `prepare` will fail, returning an undef. (See also @Borodin's note about RaiseError.)

If the driver *doesn't* send the statement to the server when `prepare` is called then driver creates and returns a statement handle that has the statement string stored within it.

> Now, in case of a failure as such, what happens to $sth? I can't call finish on it, because it is invalid.

Again, it's not clear what you mean by "invalid". (I find it helpful to try to be *really* clear about the concepts and situations I'm thinking about. Forcing myself to do that often means I find the answers to my own questions because the 'problem' was in the words I was using.)

So, as I described above, either `prepare` failed and returned an undef (or threw an exception due to RaiseError - recommended), or `prepare` returned a valid $sth.

If `prepare` returned an undef then perl will throw an exception when you try to call execute.

If `prepare` returned a valid $sth then `execute` will be called, the statement will be sent to the server, the server will detect the error, and `execute` will return false (or throw an exception if RaiseError is set - recommended).

At no point would I call $sth "invalid". Either you don't have an $sth at all because prepare failed, or you have an $sth that's perfectly valid but experienced an error when executed.

In that case calling `$sth->finish` would work but, as @ThisSuitIsBlackNot correctly noted, it would be pointless. (I should have renamed `finish` to `discard_pending_rows` many many years ago.)

Answer (score 5):

This is by far the best way to do things. Stick with `prepare` (which you need to do only once) and `execute` and avoid `do`. You should also use question marks as *placeholders* for any parameters to the query and pass the values in the call to `execute`. Amongst other things, that way handles any necessary quoting of the values for you

It is very rare that a call to `finish` or `disconnect` is necessary. You should leave them out until you know your way around `DBI` better

You're correct, `$sth` will be `undef`, and the error code and error message will be returned by `$dbh->err` and `$dbh->errstr`. Also, by default the `PrintError` option is set, which causes `DBI` to generate a warning if there are any errors in execution. If you want your program to stop altogether instead then disable `PrintError` and enable `RaiseError`

Apart from that it's really down to what you choose to do in the case of an error. For instance, some errors might be recoverable, in which case you can disable *both* `PrintError` *and* `RaiseError` and test whether the returned value is `undef`. Then you would perform some action possibly based on the error code returned by `$dbh->err`

I hope that helps

Comment: Borodin's comment regarding calls to `finish` or `disconnect` is true, but one of those rare cases did bite me in the butt when I was working with a pervasive database, so I now always explicitly call disconnect instead of expecting it to be done as part of Perl's cleanup process.

Comment: @RonBergin: If you need to call `disconnect` then you should probably also call `rollback`. Were you using `DBD::ODBC`?

Comment: @Flimzy Hmm, that's the exact opposite of what the DBI docs say: "Adding calls to finish after loop that fetches all rows is a common mistake, don't do it, it can mask genuine problems like uncaught fetch errors. When all the data has been fetched from a SELECT statement, the driver will automatically call finish for you. So you should not call it explicitly except when you know that you've not fetched all the data from a statement handle and the handle won't be destroyed soon." Out of curiosity, can you give an example where this bit you? Maybe it's driver dependent...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Perhaps. I've had problems with it in the past, and done large code audits to add it where necessary (note we did *not* add it across the board, because we *did* understand what was going on, and when it was and wasn't needed).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: If memory serves, we were dealing with connection pools shared across multiple forked processes... which, in retrospect, likely won't bite this user.  So I suppose I'll withdraw my objection and comment. :)

Comment: @Flimzy Ah, that scenario makes sense, especially since DBI has some funky driver-dependent issues w.r.t. fork.

Comment: @Borodin I was using DBD::ODBC but I was only doing selects, so no need for a rollback. The problem was that pervasive was still showing an open connection from my system after the script ended and after a number of these cases, the pervasive db reached its max connection limit which then prevented any other app to connect. Using an explicit disconnect statement solved the issue.

Comment: @RonBergin: Hmm that sounds like a bug, but it's rather late to investigate it! I guess your code was single-threaded?